# PHP forms & foreach

Tags: php, forms, foreach

Attempting to implement this into my script, however I'm not having any luck and I'm not the best are figuring things out.

### Here's for my simple 2 check box permission

```
if ($_POST['can_post'] != null)
{
    foreach($_POST['can_post'] as $can_post)
    {
        $can_post . ' ';
    }
}

if ($_POST['can_view'] != null)
{
    foreach($_POST['can_view'] as $can_view)
    {
        $can_view . ' ';
    }
}
```

$can_view & $can_post display as I'd like, if I echo from within the foreach.

IE: 2 3 6 1

That's absolutely perfect for my system, but this is not how it inserts into the query.

What I need to do is insert into my MySQL query, but whenever I do this I get an issue with values.

```
$example = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `my_table` SET `can_view` ...
```

---

To improve upon my question a little....

I'm trying to get the data from $can_view into a string which can be used on my MySQL code which isn't inside the foreach.

Comment: `$can_post . ' ';` doesn't do anything.  Are you trying to add all elements of `$_POST['can_post']` to a string and then add that to your query?  Or something else?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it was echo $can_view and $can_post. But yes, you are correct.

Comment: So is $_POST['can_view'] an array, or are you only receiving one?

Comment: The problem was...

Group 1 Can Post: CHECKED
Group 2 Can Post: empty

This would display "1" - Which is fine, as 2 isn't selected here.

Group 1 Can Post: CHECKED
Group 2 Can Post: CHECKED

This would only display "2" and not "1 2"

Comment: What's the question though?

Comment: Updated my post a little. echo $can_view displays correctly, inside the foreach. How can I display this outside of the foreach so I can insert it into my query?

Comment: What `issue with the values` do you get? And why don't you edit your question to include the complete MySQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, your main problem is that you are printing the arrays correctly to the screen but failing to store them in a way that you can send to the SQL server in a query.  Here's one way to do it assuming that's right:

```
$can_post = "";
$can_send = "";

if (isset($_POST["can_post"]) {
    foreach($_POST["can_post"] as $val) {
        $can_post .= $val . ' ';
    }
}

if (isset($_POST["can_send"]) {
    foreach($_POST["can_send"] as $val) {
        $can_sned .= $val . ' ';
    }
}

$q = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `my_table` SET `can_post` = $can_post, `can_view` = $can_view ...");
```

**EDIT:**

Havelock suggested using the [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function instead of iterating over each array, which is actually a great idea.  Here's an example:

```
$can_post = "";
$can_send = "";

if (isset($_POST["can_post"]) {
    $can_post = implode(" ", $_POST["can_post"]);
}

if (isset($_POST["can_send"]) {
    $can_send = implode(" ", $_POST["can_send"]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think that's the OP's problem too. Even better would be using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) instead of iterating over the array.

Comment: Good call on implode.  I'll edit my answer with an example using that unless you'd like to submit your own.